# Запись звука в Линукс с паузой при молчании

Tags: c++, linux, orange-pi

Как организовать запись речи через микрофон на устройстве Opange Pi (на который планирую установить Linux)? Важно, чтобы при отсутствии речи запись останавливалась (либо ставилась на паузу), начиналась новая (продолжалась старая) при возобновлении речи.

Comment: "Важно, чтобы при отсутствии речи запись останавливалась" Если ваш микро не фонит канал, то можно прямой поток аудио проверять на высоту. Но это я делал на джаве и давно, под си ищите фраймворки...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге, установил программу Audio Recorder, в которой как раз есть такой способ записи.
Установка для Ubuntu 15 и выше установка такая:
sudo add-apt-repository  ppa:audio-recorder/ppa
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall audio-recorder

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой способ:

0) ищешь типичные для голоса частоты

1) раскладываешь секундный буфер в ряд Фурье (синусы) по этим частотам

3) раскладываешь по частотам фона (шум улицы)

4) сравниваешь амплитуды

В детстве делал такое, около 50 строчек на всю програмку.